# Creating an object with hooks as property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, zustand

**Description:** 
I am using Radix-UI and I want to create a service for creating toasts:
https://www.radix-ui.com/docs/primitives/components/toast

**Problem:**
I am unable to change the statte of the `open`-hook inside the object

**How it works:**

- Any random component from anywhere in the app can add toasts to the store
- The `Toastr.tsx` watches the store `toasts`
- whenever a new object/ToastrItem is added it renders the toast
- After *5* seconds (default value) `onOpenChange`is called to set open=false through a hook. This does not work

**Toastr.tsx**

```
const Toastr = () => {
    const { toasts, setToasts } = useToastrStore();
    const eventDateRef = React.useRef(new Date());
    const timerRef = React.useRef(0);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log(toasts);
        return () => clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
    }, []);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('TOASTS:');
        console.log(toasts);
    }, [toasts]);

    return (
        <ToastProvider swipeDirection='right'>
            {toasts &&
                toasts.length > 0 &&
                isArray(toasts) &&
                toasts.map((toast: ToastrItem, idx: number) => {
                    return (
                        <Toast
                            open={toast.open}
                            onOpenChange={(openStatus: boolean) => {
                              //This does not work
                              toast.setOpen(openStatus)
                            }}
                            key={idx}
                        >
                            <ToastTitle>
                                {toast.title}
                                <h1>{toast.open}</h1>
                            </ToastTitle>
                            <ToastDescription asChild>
                                <time dateTime={eventDateRef.current.toISOString()}>{'TEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEXT'}</time>
                            </ToastDescription>
                            <ToastAction asChild altText='Goto schedule to undo'>
                                <Button variant='green' size='small'>
                                    Close
                                </Button>
                            </ToastAction>
                        </Toast>
                    );
                })}
            <ToastViewport />
        </ToastProvider>
    );
};
```

The piece of code that does not work is:

```
                            onOpenChange={(openStatus: boolean) => {
                              //This does not work
                              toast.setOpen(openStatus)
                            }}
```

My theory is that it is because of the generator i am using:

**getToast.tsx**

```
export const getToast = () => {
    const toast = new ToastObject() as ToastrItem;
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    toast.open = open;
    toast.setOpen = setOpen;
    return toast;
};
class ToastObject implements ToastrItem {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    variant: ToastrVariant;
    open: boolean;
    setOpen: (param: boolean) => void;

    constructor() {
        this.id = nanoid();
        this.title = 'test';
        this.description = 'description';
        this.variant = ToastrVariant.GOOD;
        this.open = true;
        this.setOpen = () => false;
    }
}
```

**ToastrItem.tsx**

```
export interface ToastrItem {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    variant: ToastrVariant;
    open: boolean;
    setOpen: (parameter: boolean) => any;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you using `getToast()`?

I think I see the problem without seeing the usage. React state is immutable and can only be changed by calling `setState()`. This means that if you modify a value within the current state, React doesn't know that the state has actually changed. You need to instead copy the original state, update what you need, and then call setState again.

Since you're using zustand, I'll show how you would accomplish this using that. I haven't actually tested this code, but it's the correct paradigm for what you want to do.

```js
const useToastrStore = create((set) => ({
    toasts: [],
    // addToast will update the toasts state by appending the new toast
    addToast: (toast) => set(state => ({toasts: [...state.toasts, toast]})),
    // setOpen takes a toastIndex and an open status
    setOpen: (toastIndex, openStatus) => {
        set(state => ({
                ...state,
                // map through all toasts, find the one that matches toastIndex, and change it's open status
                toasts: state.toasts.map((toast, index) => index === toastIndex ? {
                    ...toast,
                    open: openStatus
                } : {...toast})
            })
        )
    }
}))

const Toastr = () => {
    const { toasts, addToast, setOpen } = useToastrStore();

    return (
        <ToastProvider swipeDirection='right'>
            {toasts.map((toast: ToastrItem, idx: number) => (
                <Toast
                    open={toast.open}
                    onOpenChange={(openStatus: boolean) => {
                      //This does not work
                      setOpen(idx, openStatus)
                    }}
                    key={idx}
                >
                    
                </Toast>
            )}
        </ToastProvider>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks! The code is great, however, the issue i am having is that `toast: ToastrItem` requires their own `open,setOpen` hook. this means that in the array `toasts` which is of type `ToastrItem[]` each `toast: ToastrItem` has their own hook

Comment: React state cannot have class instances. If you absolutely want to do it the way you're wanting, then I would suggest you look into using mobx and mobx-react instead of zustand. mobx will 100% work how you're wanting.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense, no this is not the way i have to do it. But i need to genereate objects with properies holding states as values.